# OpenGL error in Pycharm after calling method draw_square()

Tags: python, pycharm, pyopengl

I am to draw a house using openGL and Pycharm. I am using separate functions like draw_triangle() and draw_square() to draw the house. When I call the method draw_swuare() Pycharm is showing an error. Here is my code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *



def draw_square(x1,y1, x2,y2):
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glLineWidth(5)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex2f(x1,y1)
    glVertex2f(x2,y2)
    glEnd()


def draw_triangle():
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex2f(200,300)
    glVertex2f(400, 300)
    glVertex2f(300.5, 455)

    glEnd()



def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    iterate()
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    draw_triangle()
    draw_square(200, 100, 400, 100)
    draw_square(400, 100, 400, 300)
    draw_square(400, 300, 200, 300)
    draw_square(200, 300, 200, 100)
    glutSwapBuffers()



glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500) #window size
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
wind = glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL Coding Practice") #window name
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)

glutMainLoop()
```

But when I run the program this is the error I am getting;

```
C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 41, in showScreen
    draw_square(200, 100, 400, 100)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 13, in draw_square
    glEnd()
  File "src\latebind.pyx", line 51, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.Curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\exceptional.py", line 45, in glEnd
    return baseFunction( )
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src\errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glEnd,
    cArguments = ()
)
GLUT Display callback <function showScreen at 0x000001A0D0F18040> with (),{} failed: returning None GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glEnd,
    cArguments = ()
)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is triggering this error and what should I do to fix it?